# Detecting if the Activities Overview is open?

Tags: activities-overview

I want to detect if the Activities Overview is open or not from a script. I have tried `xdotool getwindowfocus` but it just gives me the window that was focused before the Activities Overview panel was opened. Is this possible?

Comment: Read `man xlsclients`, part of the `x11-tools` package.

Comment: What about installing `wmctrl` and then running `wmctrl -l`?

Comment: @DKBose Unfortunately `wmctrl -l` doesn't show the Activities Overview. (I ran `sleep 2; wmctrl -l` and opened the Activities Overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use command

```
qdbus org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.OverviewActive
```

to see whether activity overview is open or not. If the output is true it is open.

To use `qdbus`, you may have to run
sudo apt install qttools5-dev-tools

Comment: I get an error: `qdbus: could not find a Qt installation of ' '`

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 Did you install `qttools5-dev-tools` as I mentioned at the end of the answer?

Comment: yes I did, that did nothing, but then I realized I had to install a few more packages.  It's all good now!